# Fill a column in multicol with horizontal lines

Tags: fancyhdr, multicol, includegraphics

I'm trying to make a notebook for my classes with adding my slide pictures and putting some horizontal lines as places to write some notes on. I've used multicol package to separate the page into two columns, attach the picture to the left and draw the horizontal lines in the right column. I have these two issues:

1 - My pictures are not the same size and as I've restricted their width, their height might differ. I want to draw lines to the bottom of the picture (fill the column with horizontal lines) but I couldn't find any solution.

2 - Some of the pictures overlaps with the fancyhdr footer (esp. in the pages with title) and latex doesn't initiate a newpage automatically. What should I do?

My command code using multicol:

```
\usepackage{multicol,graphicx}
\linespread{2.5}
\newcommand{\slide}[1]{%
    \setlength{\columnsep}{-3cm}
    \begin{multicols}{2}
        \null
        \includegraphics[width=6cm]{./Pic/Picture#1}
        \vfill\null
        \columnbreak
        \noindent\rule{\columnwidth}{0.4pt} \\
        \noindent\rule{\columnwidth}{0.4pt} \\
        \noindent\rule{\columnwidth}{0.4pt} \\
        \noindent\rule{\columnwidth}{0.4pt} \\
    \end{multicols}
}
```

And a sample one:
[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: Perhaps [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/79018) allows you to do that.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat Thanks a lot! That really worked.